# Python beginner stuck on creating a new pandas column from output of a package function

Tags: python, pandas, function, finance, attributeerror

I am trying to use functions from a helpful finance package to calculate the next coupon date of a bond and other information from columns in my existing dataframe. My data appears to be in the correct format because I get the result I expect when I apply the function using the data in the individual cells in the dataframe, but I get an AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year' when I try to create a new column with the results of the function as applied to each row. Thanks for any guidance. I tried to put all the relevant info in the screen capture below, but please let me know if any other info might be helpful. Thanks!

[jupyter code and error below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8fJf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have a better chance of getting assistance if you copy the code and the stack trace as text into your question instead of posting a link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are passing an entire DataFrame column into `Bond.couppcd`.  We get lazy by doing arithmetic operations on whole DataFrames at a time, but external modules don't know that.  `Bond.couppcd` expects to get one value at a time.  You'll have to have a loop where you do something like

```
df.at[i,'pcd'] = Bond.couppcd(settlement=df.at[i,'Settlement_date'], maturity=df.at[i,'Maturity_date'],frequency=2, bases=1)
```

Pandas will create the column if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of that. I've never done that kind of looping to create a new column but will play around with it and give it a try.

Comment: You should be able to do `df.at[i,'pcd'] = ...` and I should fix the answer to say that.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how to define i in the code you wrote. But, I tried this: and it seems to have worked: for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[ind, "pcd"] = Bond.couppcd(settlement=df.loc[ind, "Settlement_Date"], maturity=df.loc[ind, "Maturity_Date"],frequency=2, basis=1)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Tim's helpful response diagnosing the problem, I googled how to iterate a function over rows and came up with this, which isn't fast but gets the job done:

for ind, row in df.iterrows(): df.loc[ind, "pcd"] = Bond.couppcd(settlement=df.loc[ind, "Settlement_Date"], maturity=df.loc[ind, "Maturity_Date"],frequency=2, basis=1)